# Regex-negation to exclude an element

Tags: ruby

I have the following strings:

- `"4 sprigs of fresh rosemary"`
- `"1 x 600 g jar of quality white beans"`

and I would like to exclude everything that's before `"of"` like this:

- `"fresh rosemary"`
- `"quality white beans"`

I tried using `gsub`, but I can't find the proper regex.

Comment: just do a split on `of` then get the second item.

Comment: "I tried using a gsub but I can't find the proper regex !" post your attempts..

Comment: Why are you using `gsub`? It does not make sense.

Comment: So to select all the elements after "of" I used the following regex (as advised below : /(?<=\sof\s)(?!.*\sof\s).+/ 

To select the elements before of (a pinch, 500g, 30kg, 4 cloves,,) I used the following regex : 
/(^\d\/\d)|(^.*\d*)\s(g\s|l|kg|tablespoons|tablespoon|a bunch|a pinch|sprigs|cloves)|(^\d+)/

Hope this helped someone. Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using `gsub`. It does not make sense.

```
"4 sprigs of fresh rosemary".sub(/.*(?=of)/, "")
# => "of fresh rosemary"

"1 x 600 g jar of quality white beans".sub(/.*(?=of)/, "")
# => "of quality white beans"
```

By the way, what you described and what you are expecting do not match.

Or,

```
"1 x 600 g jar of quality white beans".sub(/.*of\s*/, "")
# => "quality white beans"

"4 sprigs of fresh rosemary".sub(/.*of\s*/, "")
# => "fresh rosemary"
```

Comment: The first example includes `"of"`, the second example works fine :) Not sure why this was down voted.

Comment: @Kris Exactly. The OP wrote "exclude everything that's before 'of'", which does not mean to exclude "of".

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. Guessing a typo in their question.

Answer (score 0):

Not using a regex:

```
"4 sprigs of fresh rosemary".split('of ').last
# => "fresh rosemary"
```

Would not work if the sentence had the word `"of"` more than once.

Comment: It does not make difference if "of" appears more than once.

Comment: `"4 sprigs of fresh rosemary of thyme".split('of ').last # => "thyme"`

Comment: You can define a limit: `"4 sprigs of fresh rosemary of thyme".split('of ', 2).last # => "fresh rosemary of thyme"` Check [the documentation of String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) for details.

Comment: @HolgerJust That would exclude only the first "of" and before. It doesn't exclude everything before the second "of".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `match` method on a string using a regex.

```
"4 sprigs of fresh rosemary".match(/of (.+)/)[1]
=> "fresh rosemary"
```

The brackets around .+ deterimne a substring to return in MatchData that you then call with [1]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option if you always want the end of the line after `"of"` even if there are multiples of `"of"` in a sentence

```
paragraph = "4 sprigs of fresh rosemary
             1 x 600 g jar of quality white beans
             I have a love of many things including a love of fresh rosemary
             I have an of for all things but of the things I of, I of quality white beans the most
             I will reject this offensive flower"
paragraph.scan(/(?<=\sof\s)(?!.*\sof\s).+/)
#=> ["fresh rosemary", "quality white beans", 
#    "fresh rosemary", "quality white beans the most"]
```

This regex say:

- `(?<=\sof\s)` : Look behind for the literal `" of "`
- `(?!.*\sof\s)` : Look ahead to make sure there are no more occurrences of `" of "`
- `.+` expect one or more characters after the final `" of "`

[Example](http://rubular.com/r/cQjxjlknkG)

Comment: Thank you ! this worked perfectly for me !! If I could I would upvote :)